# Animation start/stop within AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask

I need to start animation on imageview in Pre-execute and stop it in Post-execute but app force stopped.

> error: Caused by:
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

here is my code:

```
    class RefreshAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),
            R.anim.rotation);

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                imageView.animate().cancel();
            }
        });

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                imageView.startAnimation(anim);
            }
        });

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

}
```

**THANKS IN ADVANCE!!**

Comment: You don't need to use `runOnUiThread` other then `doInBackground()` just make sure you are not accessing any view inside `doInBackground()` directly.

Comment: Thanks for answer #ADM i will check it

Comment: Since `onPostExecute` runs on UI thread, you do not have to user `runOnUiThread`. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for answer #Chithra

Comment: Thanks #ADM it is working FINE now :):):)